# releasing objects from memory in the right way

Tags: objective-c, linked-list, automatic-ref-counting

I have a linked list of objects that I want to release. Each node has a strong reference to the next one.

When releasing all objects, is it enough to set the first one to `nil` (in ARC mode), or do I need to make all references to the next node a weak reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read this:
[Apple Memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)

Possible duplicate of:
[does setting an object to nil with ARC cause a release of its properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581040/does-setting-an-object-to-nil-with-arc-cause-a-release-of-its-properties)